# MYSQL Convert Integer to Hours:Minutes

Tags: mysql

So, i have an integer column with value : 4995,
i want to convert it to Hours:Mins format using :

```
cast(concat(floor(sum(4995)/60),':',mod(sum(4995)/60,60)) As time) as total_min

results : 83:23:00
```

It resulted two mins less that what it should be :

```
select 4995/60
results : 83.2500
```

Using `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(4995*60);` resulted : `83:15:00`

So, what is the right query for converting integer to hours:minutes time format.

Thank you.